# How to initialize an instance of socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I have discovered that there are at least 2 ways to go about doing this. The first way creates an HTTP server, although the 2nd way doesn't.
I am not able to find any concrete tutorial regarding this.

Case I

```
 var app = require('express')(); 
 var http = require('http').Server(app); 
 var io = require('socket.io')(http);
 http.listen(3000);
```

Case II

```
var app = require('express')(); 
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app.listen(port));
```

How are the two methods different? And why doesn't the second method require an HTTP server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`app.listen()` creates the http server for you (a shortcut that express lets you use).

Here's the code for `app.listen()`:

```
app.listen = function(){
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

This Express code is [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L557).